# indexing and pivoting (data frame, pandas, python)

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, dataframe, psycopg2

I am getting a table from a Postgre SQL query via psycopg2 module. The table looks something like:

```
ct                          i          v
1 3429-03-19 20:00:00      1          45
2 3433-02-10 21:00:00      1          65
3 3433-02-10 22:00:00      2          44
```

I am then converting this to a data frame. I need to downsample i and v to daily according to the date (datetime.date) in the ct column. Then Pivot the data frame so the date would be the index and columns would be daily medians of i and v.

```
table=cur.fetchall() #resulting table from psycopg2 (the SQL query)
col = ['Date', 'Daily i', 'Daily v']
pt_df = pd.DataFrame (rows, columns=col)
pt_df2 = pt_df.set_index(['Date'])
pt_df2
```

I tried this to set the date as the index column but I am getting an error of OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 3429-03-19 20:00:00. How can I fix this? I tried converting the ct column into pd.to_datetime. But that also resulted in an error.

I tried pivoting the df like this:

```
df = rows
pt_df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["Date"], columns = col, aggfunc=[np.median(df, axis=1, 'i'), np.median(df, axis=1, 'v')])
pt_df2
```

But I also get an error with this. I am really struck on this.

Comment: Are you really freaking dealing with data of year 3429 of the Gregorian calendar????

Comment: Yes, all the years are between 3000 to 3600 range

Comment: Then don't use nanosecond precision as it makes no sense to be nanosecond precise for something that will happen a millennium from now

Answer (score 1):

Numpy datetime64 only has 292 years (1678 AD - 2262 AD) at nanosecond resolution.  See the [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) for more details.

If that is enough range, you could bias your dates by subtracting 1322 years (1322=3000-1678), doing your calculations and then adding 1322 years back.

Microsecond resolution would, of course, work without biasing your dates.